# Which drawer is being moved in Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

My project has two Navigation Drawers. One on the `left` using `start` and another on the `right` using `end`.

As it is suggested here [push activity on the right when open drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577630/push-activity-on-the-right-when-open-drawer)

I got my activity to move right whenever I am opening my drawer. But the problem is it is moving right, on the movement of both the drawers. It makes sense to move right every-time because I have only assigned it to move right whenever any drawer moves.

My question is how to detect which drawer is being moved so that I can either move it right or left based on my preference ?

Here is a Github repo of the project https://github.com/ishanatmuz/StudioHello

Comment: What do you get  in the `onDrawerSlide()` first parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Tags
tag your drawers and in the onDrawerOpened check this tag

example:

```
rightDrawer.setTag("Right");
```

---

```
@Override
void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
if(view.getTag().toString().equals("Right"))
          //codeHere
}
```