# How do I create an android navigation bar that pushes aside the current view to right?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I need a navigation bar that doesn't slideIn above the current view (the usual overlapping stype), instead it should be as in new ebay app (as if scrolling the wallpaper in homescreen with more than one page). Is it possible to add this effect to [material-design-navigation-view](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)? How do I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sliding Menu Library for your requirement. Here is the link to that library

[Sliding Menu Library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

And if you are using Android Studio then see this link to add it in your project

[Importing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079072/how-to-import-slidingmenu-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way to really do this. However, this thread of StackOverflow will help you: [push activity on the right when open drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577630/push-activity-on-the-right-when-open-drawer)

Another GitHub library that may suit your need is: [Material Drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). You can download the demo on Google Play Store (same name). A similar approach is the Persistent Header Drawer