# Move screen with navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have implemented drawer navigation in android which is visually look like this

[image]

But I want a navigation drawer like this

[image]

I have tried alot but unable to do so. I have tried the following code:

```
 drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                //Called when a drawer's position changes.
                drawer.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout).setTranslationX(drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                //Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
                //The drawer is interactive at this point.
                // If you have 2 drawers (left and right) you can distinguish
                // them by using id of the drawerView. int id = drawerView.getId();
                // id will be your layout's id: for example R.id.left_drawer
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                // Called when the drawer motion state changes. The new state will be one of STATE_IDLE, STATE_DRAGGING or STATE_SETTLING.
            }
        });
```

I am not getting the correct result. Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: I am talking about drawer movement.. I want to move screen with drawer as shown in second image

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577630/push-activity-on-the-right-when-open-drawer