# Move layout elements using animation

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Now I have a simple layout like this:

```
-----------------------------------
   button1       |       button2  
-----------------------------------
 Welcome to my App.
```

When the user clicks button1, I want to show a side bar from right (swipes in smoothly), and move two buttons smoothly to left side:

```
-----------------------------------
button1|button2|      Side bar    
---------------|
Welcome        |
to my App.     |    some text that
               |    shows some infos
```

---

And when I click button1 again, the sidebar should disappear (swiping to right) and we got the same layout as the first one.

Now I have two questions:

1. The side bar that I want is not really a *navigation bar*, so I do not want to use the `sidebar` in Android. Is there any other alternatives better for my use?
2. How can I achieve that, when the side bar appears from the right, move everything (including two buttons and text) to the left to give space for side bar? Is there a way to do this properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577630/push-activity-on-the-right-when-open-drawer

Answer (score 0):

You can use   TranslateAnimation like this

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 150);  //use Sidebar.length() to move according to sidebar                          
                            anim.setDuration(1000);
                            anim.setFillAfter(true);
                            animWindow.setDuration(1000);
                            animWindow.setFillAfter(true);
                            button1.setAnimation(anim);
                            button2.setAnimation(anim);
```