# Push content when drawer opens in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to slide the contents of scaffold when drawers open. Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577630/push-activity-on-the-right-when-open-drawer)
but in jetpack compose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution...

```kotlin
// This is optional if you need to open/close the drawer programmatically
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

// We need the drawer state to check:
// 1. if it is opened or closed
// 2. request to open/close it
// 3. get the drawer's offset (and do the slide of the content)
val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)

// Drawer's width. It will be updated later in LaunchedEffect
var drawerWidth by remember {
    mutableStateOf(drawerState.offset.value)
}
// As soon the user move the drawer, the content must move in sync.
// So here we're creating a derived state of the drawer state 
// to update the content position.
val contentOffset = remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        drawerState.offset.value
    }
}
// The scaffold state contains the drawer state.
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(
    drawerState = drawerState
)

Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    drawerContent = {
        Box {
            // your drawer content here...
        }
    }
) {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        // Here's the content's offset calculation logic
        val xPos = (abs(drawerWidth) - abs(contentOffset.value))
        Column(
            // Set the content's offset
            Modifier.offset(
                x = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                    max(0.dp, xPos.toDp() - 56.dp)
                }
            )
        ) {
            // Optional: opening the drawer using a button
            Button(onClick = {    
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    drawerState.open()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Open Drawer")
            }
        }
    }
}
// Important! Initializing the drawerWidth
SideEffect {
    if (drawerWidth == 0f) {
        drawerWidth = drawerState.offset.value
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

**Warning!** This solution has a problem: as you can see, I'm using a hardcoded value `56.dp`. This is because the Material Design library uses this value as end padding of the drawer. You can see this constant in the [`Drawer.kt`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Drawer.kt) file in Material Design library.

```
private val EndDrawerPadding = 56.dp
```

Comment: All credit to you for the idea and for teaching me this cool kotlin trick with ```with``` blocks. But it seems to me like if the 56dp is already baked in, then drawerWidth is just a proxy for screen width, which requires very little maneuvering.  So I opted to use ```.offset(x = max(0.dp,with(LocalDensity.current){(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp + scaffoldState.drawerState.offset.value.toDp()-56.dp)}))```